# alternating digit sum

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to proof that if

$t | A(x) \Rightarrow t|x$ with $t \in D(b+1)$

where $A(x)$ is the alternating digit sum, $D$ contains alls dividers of $b+1$ and $b$ is the base of $x$.

My current steps:

$t |(b+1) \iff b+1 = t*k$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

$\iff b = t*k-1 \iff b \equiv -1\pmod{t}$

$\Rightarrow b^{a} \equiv (-1)^a \pmod{t}$

I have no idea how to connect those steps with the alternating digit sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be represented as $x = a_n a_{n-1} \cdots a_1 a_0$ in base $b$. Consequently,
$$x = a_0 + a_1 b+\cdots a_n b^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i b^i, \tag 1$$
and 
$$A(x) = a_0-a_{1}+a_{2}-\cdots \pm a_n =\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^ia_i. \tag 2$$
Now use the fact that $b^i \equiv (-1)^i \mod{t}$ to prove that $x\equiv A(x) \mod{t}$.